# Get count for each record mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables name `event` and `checkin`
It is joined with `event.id` to `checkin.event_id`
i want to get count of number of checkins in `checkin` for all records in `event`

So far i have done this and it returns the value but it returns the count for the entries in `checkin` table

I want to get no of checkins of each `event.id`

How do i get that
I am using this query right now

```
SELECT e.id,COUNT(*) from checkin c 
LEFT JOIN event e ON (c.event_id=e.id) 
GROUP by e.id
```

which is giving me result like this

```
event_id    COUNT(*)
1             2
5             5
7             8
```

Which is fine but i want result like this

```
event_id    COUNT(*)
1             2
2             0
3             0
4             0
5             5
6             0
7             8
```

Hope my question is clear now
thank you

Comment: Maybe `count(e.id)` rather than `count(*)`? That way you'll get zeroes instead of ones when no events are matched. I'm also wondering if you need to reverse the order of the tables in the join.

Comment: You want your left join the other way around.

Comment: @paulKienitz do you mean like this? `SELECT e.id,COUNT(*) from event e LEFT JOIN checkin c ON (e.id=c.event_id) GROUP by e.id` it gives me 1 in every record. It doesnt count

Comment: It's very unlikely you want an outer join along with `count(*)`. You probably want to count non-null values in a specific column.

Comment: @shawnt00 i just want to join `count` with `event` table so that i can see in the array in which i store my query that how many checkins are there for each columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the join and count non-null event_id:

```
SELECT e.d, COUNT(c.event_id) AS check_count
FROM event e LEFT OUTER JOIN checkin c ON c.event_id = e.id
GROUP BY e.event_id
```

Try adding `COUNT(e.id)` so you can compare it to `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(c.event_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

use the below query with an alias for the counter

```
SELECT e.id,COUNT(c.*) as check_count from checkin c 
LEFT JOIN event e ON (c.event_id=e.id) 
GROUP by e.id
```

Also i recommend you to use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*` functions that are deprecated

Comment: i am getting error with (c.*). Are you sure mysql supports that way

Comment: Please Post  what is the error message that you are seeing?

Comment: No, I didn't expect that to work either but MySQL is pretty tolerant so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Sourabh probably meant "c.*" as shorthand for a non-null column from c.

Comment: @Sourabh here is the error code `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as check_count from `

Comment: You can just replace `count(c.*)`  with just `count(*)` and try once, even though the above query of mine should not give any error. If the error is because of  `*` then you try one of the column name from that table in this manner `count(c.event_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply as-

```
select event_id, count(id) 
from checkin group by event_id;
```

If due to some specific reason you want to cross check that event table should have corresponding rows then you can do as per below-

```
SELECT e.id, COUNT(c.id) 
FROM event AS e
JOIN checkin AS c ON c.event_id=e.id 
GROUP BY e.id;
```

If you want to show event id even does not exist in checkin table then you can do as per below-

```
SELECT e.id, COUNT(c.id) 
FROM event AS e
LEFT JOIN checkin AS c ON c.event_id=e.id 
GROUP BY e.id;
```